# Analyzing multiple prepositional phrases in "I am sitting in the car across the street."

Tags: prepositions, phrases

Consider the following sentence:

> I am sitting in the car across the street.

Do we say that there are two prepositional phrases in the sentence modifying "sitting" (in the car, across the street)?

Or do we say that there is one prepositional phrase modifying "sitting" (in the car), and then another prepositional phrase modifying "car" (across the street)? In this case it looks like there is one prepositional phrase inside of another.

Comment: [The most likely reading is that:] the verb *sitting* is taking the preposition phrase (PP) *in the car across the street* as a Locative Complement (the PP is not modifying the verb!). Within this PP the noun *car* is being modified by the PP *across the street*. [There is a less likely reading which we could paraphrase as *Across the street, the man is sitting in the car*. In this reading *in the car* is the Locative Complement of *sitting* and *Across the street* is an Adjunct (sentence Modifier).

Comment: The most plausible analysis is that the PP "in the car across the street" is a complement of sitting, in which the PP "across the street" is modifying "car".

Answer (score 1):

In terms of grammar, it can be analyzed several ways. Here's the first three I found:

> "I am sitting in the car and I am sitting across the street."
> "I am sitting in the car which is across the street."
> "I am sitting in the car and I am across the street."

where "across the street" modifies the subject "I" in the last one.

The best fit is "I'm sitting in the car which is across the street" because it would be more natural to put "across the street" before "in the car" in the other two sentences:

> "I am sitting across the street in the car."
> "I am across the street sitting in the car."

Comment: Thanks.

It seems like in the previous example, you were able to link two prepositional phrases to two separate verbs. What about something like this?

"I went to NYC with my brother"

Comment: What do you think?

Comment: Then is this sentence "I am sitting in the car across the street" still correct even when the sentence is written to mean "I am sitting in the car" and "I am sitting across the street"?